# Android android.intent.action.SEND youtube video

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube, intentfilter

If you hit the share button on a Youtube video, it's shared as `text/plain`. In my application though, I only want to receive youtube URLs and not all other things that are shared with `text/plain`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No. You cannot filter on the contents of an `Intent` extra, and so there is no good way for you to arrange to only appear in `text/plain` choosers containing YouTube URLs and not any other `text/plain` choosers.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks anyway!